# Display a calculated value from models in a template in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I want to show the calculated discount under every product. The code below has no errors, but it does not display the value.

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
CATEGORIES = (  
    ('Electronics', 'Electronics'),
    ('Clothing', 'Clothing'),
)

class Products(models.Model):
    Image = models.FileField()
    ProductName = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default='')
    Brand = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default='')
    OriginalPrice = models.IntegerField(default = '')
    Price = models.IntegerField(default = '')
    Category = models.CharField(max_length = 250, choices = CATEGORIES)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Products'

    def DiscountCalc(self):
        Discount = (Price/OriginalPrice) * 100
        return self.Discount

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.ProductName
```

This is the template
**index.html**:

```
{% for product in AllProducts %}
    <article class="product col-sm-3">
        <a href="#" class="prodlink">
            <img src="{{ product.Image.url }}" class="prodimg img-responsive">
            <p class="prodname">{{ product.ProductName }}</p>
            <span class="origprice">₹{{ product.OriginalPrice }}</span>
            <span class="price">₹{{ product.Price }}</span>
            <div class="discount">
                <p>{{ product.Discount }}% off</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You code wouldn't run at all. Please post the real code. Edit it into the question don't post as a comment.

Comment: I have posted the full code

Comment: Your code still wouldn't run

Comment: It is running for me

Comment: `Discount = (Price/OriginalPrice) * 100` should give you undefined variable errors

Comment: It didn't give any errors but it didn't show anything, that is why i posted the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to make a property :

```
@property
def Discount(self):
    return (self.Price/self.OriginalPrice) * 100
```

So now you can use product.Discount :)

Docs here [Django model-methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#model-methods)

Answer (score 1):

1)Defining a local variable and Returning a class variable will return null

2)You have to have the same name in models and template

models.py

```
def DiscountCalc(self):
    Discount = (Price/OriginalPrice) * 100
    return Discount
```

index.html

```
{% for product in AllProducts %}
    <article class="product col-sm-3">
        <a href="#" class="prodlink">
            <img src="{{ product.Image.url }}" class="prodimg img-responsive">
            <p class="prodname">{{ product.ProductName }}</p>
            <span class="origprice">₹{{ product.OriginalPrice }}</span>
            <span class="price">₹{{ product.Price }}</span>
            <div class="discount">
                <p>{{ product.DiscountCalc }}% off</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```